# @Async annotated method doesn't operate Asynchronously when called by controller

Tags: spring

I'm toying with asynchronous calls to reduce some waiting time on client side when calling a page.

As a experiement i have a controller that calls a pojo with a method annotated with @Async. In that menthod i sleep for 10000 ms to simulation operation to test whether my theory works, and it seems not to. Code below and further information can be found after it:

Test Controller

```
@Conroller
public class TestController {
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String testAsyncCall() {

new AsyncTestClass().asyncOpOne();

return "secondpage";
}
}
```

Asynchronous Class containing the @Async annotated method

```
public class AsyncTestClass {
@Async
public void asyncOpOne() {
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("done working");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //
    }
}
}
```

Now from my understanding when the client makes the call to "/test" in their browser the controller should return call the asynchronous method and instantly return "secondpage" to be rendered.

What is happening is that the controller **doesn't** return the second page until the 10000 ms in the asynchronous call has finished, only then it returns the secondpage.

FYI
@EnableAsync is added to one of my config files (using Java Configuration).

What am i doing wrong here that is causing the controller to wait for the async to finish its sleep before continuing?

Comment: You aren't using the Spring configured instance but are constructing a new one yourself... Use the one configured by spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you clarify, i don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: You are doing `new AsyncTestClass` which means you are constructing an instance yourself, outside the control of spring so basically your `@Async` is useless. Add a bean for the `AsyncTestClass` and inject that into your controller.

Comment: So does that mean all methods i annotate @Async should be in a bean and injected?

Comment: @Aeseir Correct, otherwise you don't get the AOP-enabled proxy.

Comment: correct... It is no different as an `@Transactional` method, spring uses AOP to accomplish that behavior.

Comment: Brilliant thanks guys. @M.Deinum please add answer so i can accept it as token of appreciation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring uses AOP to apply `@Async` behavior to your beans (the same goes for `@Transactional` for instance).

Spring will only apply AOP to beans it knows, as you are constructing a new instance outside of the scope of Spring the `@Async` does nothing. Simply add it as a bean to your configuration and inject it into your controller.

```
@Bean
public AsyncTestClass asyncTestClass() {
    return new AsyncTestClass():
}
```

Then in your calling class.

```
@Conroller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncTestClass asyncTestClass;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String testAsyncCall() {

        asyncTestClass.asyncOpOne();
        return "secondpage";
    }
}
```